# How to identify installed apps where I participate as beta tester

Tags: applications, google-play-store

On my Moto G (peregrine) with Android 4.4.4 I installed some apps where I joined beta tester programs long time ago (via log-in from a googlegroup etc.), and also just some weeks ago where no more group joining was necessary.

As I lost overview of the apps where I am beta tester:

How can I identify all apps where I a take part in beta testing?

(looking on my device intensively, also in GooglePlay settings and a general internet search were without success for my to find this out)

Comment: IIRC you can't rate apps you have a beta version of installed.

Comment: Why would you want to identify them though. If the beta testing has ended they'll inform you, dish out the formal app and stop informing you AFAIK. Else it's more likely the beta has not ended yet.

Comment: @JoshHolland : I have apps where I take part in beta testing and I am able to rate them in play store. So this cannot be the criteria I am looking for.

Comment: @XiangJi : My beta apps I am using are apps that have regular updates and thus have regular beta releases as well. So Beta testing will not end, I assume.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I finally found a (cumbersome?) way to find out whetre I have an app as a beta tester:

Have ideally a desktop PC with a browser and go to https://play.google.com and be sure to have logged in there with your google account.

There you can list all apps (in a kind of gallery) that are connected to your account, and even what apps are installed right now to any of your android devices that uses your google account.

Hover over one app there and you have a link for each app that leads to the indiviual item on play.google.com for each app.

For example:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.generalmagic.magicearth

Since summer 2015 you can take part in app beta testing (when supported by the developer) by visiting a special link for each app, like
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.generalmagic.magicearth

So you just need to take the first link for the "official" app,
and replace the part of the URL

```
/store/apps/details?id=
```

with

```
/apps/testing/
```

Then you can have at least three cases:

1. You are not allowed to take part in beta testing for this app.
2. You can become a beta tester for this app, when invited or it is a public beta test.
3. or you can see that you are already a beta tester for this app.

Anybody knows a more simple way?

Comment: If only it can be automated... I'm thinking of a way to automate it, but still not sure...

Answer (score 1):

Believe in future!!!

Because in these days of June/July 2016, there is a new feature in the Play Store app:

After selecting "My apps & games" I can see now:

`Installed ... All ...`**`Beta`**  <- There you can see all beta apps now !!

(available at least on two devices with android 4.4.4 and 5.1)

Comment: Confirmed on Android 6.0.1, so I believe it's device independent, and only depends on Play Store version :)

Comment: Does this also apply to the web app under play.google.com?

Comment: so far I have NOT seen any beta section when browsing to play.google.com to see all my android apps on different devices.